Concatenation of words and expressions
Introduction
I am trying to create a string filter function based on a given filter string (that is, the filter is formed from a string)
I have already come up with and written code for expressions like "some+string|(test+(another|value))"
Problem
I want to parse expressions from a string based on the operators in this string
I would like to use two characters as operators: "+" and "|"
"+": In the case when it occurs next to strings, it should indicate their concatenation. When it occurs with another expression in parentheses, it should denote concatenation with the result of the expression in these brackets (further on the example should become clear).
"|": should denote "logical or". A simple example: (a|b) = ['a', 'b']
As I said earlier, I figured out how to do this when there is no nesting in expressions in parentheses, and now I do not know how to implement getting the result I need when the brackets are nested inside each other
EXAMPLE 1 (the desired result)
input string: ((some+test)|((figure+(10|20))+(circle+figure|(3d)))+(free|frau)
output array:
[
    "some test free", "figure 10 circle figure free", "figure 20 circle figure free", "figure 10 3d free", "figure 20 3d free",
    "some test frau", "figure 10 circle figure frau", "figure 20 circle figure frau", "figure 10 3d frau", "figure 20 3d frau",
];

EXAMPLE 2
input string: "((some+test)|((figure+(10|20))+(circle+figure|(3d)))|(free|frau)"
output array:
[
    "some test", "figure 10 circle figure", "figure 10 3d", "figure 20 circle figure", "figure 20 3d", "free", "frau"
];

It seems to me that with the help of examples it should be clear what I want to get as a result.
I've been trying to break this task down into smaller ones, and now I have a function that splits expressions in parentheses into arrays and subarrays with operators. But I still can't recursively process these arrays given the logic of the + and | operators.
My helper function:


function parseLogicalExpression(expression) {
  const result = [];
  let currentExpression = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < expression.length; i++) {
    const char = expression[i];
    if (char === '(') {
      if (currentExpression !== '') {
        result.push(currentExpression);
        currentExpression = '';
      }
      let stack = 1;
      let subExpression = '';
      while (stack > 0) {
        i++;
        if (expression[i] === '(') {
          stack++;
        } else if (expression[i] === ')') {
          stack--;
        }
        if (stack > 0) {
          subExpression += expression[i];
        }
      }
      result.push(parseLogicalExpression(subExpression));
    } else if (char === '+' || char === '|') {
      if (currentExpression !== '') {
        result.push(currentExpression);
        currentExpression = '';
      }
      result.push(char);
    } else {
      currentExpression += char;
    }
  }

  if (currentExpression !== '') {
    result.push(currentExpression);
  }

  return result;
}

let expression = "((some+test)|(figure+(10|20))+(circle+figure|(3d)))"; // !!! This expression differs from that in the examples. It has been changed so that it is not too cumbersome

console.log(parseLogicalExpression(expression));
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}





and | have to handle another parseLogicalExpression(), like you are doing already with (...then, to detect an end of expression you have to have a stack of (, ), + and | counter


do you have an operator precedence? ... of + and |? what is 'a+b|c'?

@NinaScholz a+b|c = ['ab', 'c']

but in general, it is assumed that the expression about | is always enclosed in parentheses

This is basically the same as regular expressions, except that it doesn't need an operator for concatenation. So just remove all + characters and you'll get the equivalent regexp.

Even if they have the regexp, they still need to produce the strings it could match. Not sure that brings them closer to a solution.

In the initial challenge your results don't include spaces, but then in example 1 and 2, there results have spaces that are not present in the input, and then in your code there is no trace of adding spaces. What is the rule?

@trincot Yes, you're right! I deleted these entries so as not to confuse the reader. Thank you

Both examples have more opening than closing parentheses... Can you fix that?

I think you will find this Q&A to be useful

I would suggest doing this in two phases:

Build a binary tree while parsing the input string, using the Shunting yard algorithm
Produce all strings from that tree

Here is an implementation:


class Node {
    constructor(value, left, right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

function parseToTree(expression) {
    const precedence = { "+": 2, "|": 1, "(": -1, ")": 0, "": 0 };
    const operators = [];
    const operands = [];
    for (const token of expression.match(/[^+|()\s]+|\S?/gs)) {
        if (token in precedence) {
            if (token !== "(") {
                while (precedence[operators.at(-1)] >= precedence[token]) {
                    if (operands.length < 2) throw new Error("Parser: Syntax error"); 
                    operands.push(new Node(operators.pop(), ...operands.splice(-2)));
                }
            }
            if (token && token !== ")") operators.push(token);
            else operators.pop(); // "("
        } else {
            operands.push(token);
        }
    }
    if (operands.length != 1) throw new Error("Parser: Syntax error");
    return operands.pop();
}

function* product(a, b, sep=" ") {
    b = [...b];
    for (const x of a) {
        for (const y of b) {
            yield x + sep + y;
        }
    }
}

function* stringsInTree(root) {
    if (typeof root === "string") {
        yield root;
    } else if (root.value === "+") {
        yield* product(stringsInTree(root.left), stringsInTree(root.right));
    } else {
        yield* stringsInTree(root.left);
        yield* stringsInTree(root.right);
    }
}

function displayStrings(expression) {
    for (const s of stringsInTree(parseToTree(expression))) {
        console.log(s);
    }
}

// demo: example 2
displayStrings("(some+test)|((figure+(10|20))+(circle+figure|(3d)))|(free|frau)");



